# OpenGL blending issue alpha being ignored

Tags: windows, winapi, opengl

I'm working on a Rendition Verite wrapper to run games designed for it on modern systems using OpenGL.

One of the games I'm trying to fix has a weird issue. Blending ignores the alpha value. It's almost as if blending is disabled.

To test if blending is working just before swapping buffers (with game graphics already rendered) if I do this (disabling the shader):

```
GLint p{};                                  glGetIntegerv(GL_CURRENT_PROGRAM, &p);
glUseProgramObjectARB(0);
GLint tex{};
glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D, &tex);

bool b = glIsEnabled(GL_BLEND);

glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
//glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_ZERO);
//glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
GLfloat alpha = 0.3f;
glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, alpha);
glVertex3f(320.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glColor4f(.0, 1.0, 0.0, alpha);
glVertex3f(0.0, 479.0, 0.0);
glColor4f(.0, 0.0, 1.0, alpha);
glVertex3f(639.0, 479.0, 0.0);
glEnd();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
```

On the game that doesn't work (SODA off-road) it produces  a solid triangle overlaid on top of the game.

SODA renders to the framebuffer. Setting glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_ZERO) or glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE) also makes no difference.

In the games that do work, this overlays a transparent triangle (SRC_ALPHA), black triangle (GL_ZERO, GL_ZERO) or nothing (GL_ZERO, GL_ONE). As far as I can tell this should just work when rendering to the framebuffer; this games doens't use render to texture.

I don't need to render a giant triangle on-screen, it's just that the alpha textures don't render correctly in my shader.

```
if(alpha==0.0)
   discard;
```

does work, but it's not blending.

glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS) is set. glGetIntegerv(GL_BLEND) returns true;

My question is how is the above block not blending? The results are exactly the same on an nvidia GTX1060 and Intel HD4000, HD2000.

I tried blend factors:

```
    glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_ZERO);
```

and

```
    glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE);
```

with no effect. It's like blending isn't enabled. But OpenGL query for GL_BLEND returns GL_TRUE.

It works just fine in the other games that I've got working.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include the answer. Instead, post an answer to your own question. Unless the question in itself cannot be answered (e.g. because it doesn't contain enough information) or the answer is not useful to others (e.g. because it was caused by a typo or programming oversight), then remove your question.

Comment: Sorry, could't find a way to mark it as resolved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turned out to be **glLogicOp** being set to **GL_COPY**.

Rendition games support raster ops and this particular one was setting the RRedline mode to **V_ALUMODE_SRC**, which I translated to to **GL_COPY**.

Raster ops appear to disable blending (actually makes sense):

```
if (logicOp != GL_COPY)
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_LOGIC_OP);
else
    glDisable(GL_COLOR_LOGIC_OP);
```

appears to do the trick.